# SSH password stopped working

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

So, I tried to connect to a MySQL Database through an SSH tunnel as usual and it prompted me for the password to my ssh key. I entered it as usual and allthough I am 100% sure I entered the correct password, it kept asking and thus failed.

I tried other things like a pull from a github repo, logging onto a server and so forth. It seems like my ssh-key has a different password all of the sudden but date of last modification is more than a year ago.

What is going on? It'd be quite a bummer if I had to change my ssh-key.

I already tried to change it:

```
$ ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.old_ssh/id_rsa
Enter old passphrase:
Key has comment '/Users/noxoc/.old_ssh/id_rsa'
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

However I still get the same behaviour.

Ran it again with `-vvv`:

```
$ ssh-keygen -vvv -p -f ~/.old_ssh/id_rsa
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
```

That looks promising and bad at the same time.

Comment: Try running ssh with the `-v` switch (or possibly `-vv` for yet more details). Also, if you have access to the server-side logs, check to see if those contain anything of value. That you are able to change the private key passphrase *strongly* suggests that this isn't really about the private key passphrase at all, but rather something else.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling see updated question. This might get us somewhere.

Comment: I was thinking about `ssh` specifically (using it to try to connect and see what errors you get). It's really weird that you were able to change the passphrase once and not again. That smells a little like a barfed key file unfortunately. Do you have a backup to compare it against?

Comment: The *easiest* solution might very well be to just generate a new key. Since you shouldn't be using the same private key with more than one host anyway, it shouldn't be *too* hard to replace the public key on the remote host.